# Scroll to the next div

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want that, whenever someone scrolls down on my web page it makes an auto/smooth scroll to the next

```
div class="bigCards"
```

ty

Comment: Bro, you use JavaScript for these kinds of actions. I'd recommend you add it into your list of tags.

Comment: Also... Are you sure you want to do this? That would really frustrate me if I was on your website.

Comment: I understand the pro's and cons of using. From a desing view, yeah is goint to be a good add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need jquery also:

```js
    var delay = false;

    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if (delay) return;

     delay = true;
     setTimeout(function() {
      delay = false
     }, 200)

     var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

     var a = document.getElementsByClassName("anchor");
     if (wd < 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
       if (t >= 20) break;
      }
     } else {
      for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
       if (t < -20) break;
      }
     }
     $('html,body').stop(true,false).animate({
       scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      }, {
       queue: false,
       duration: 1000
      }

     );

    });
```

```css
.fullpage{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%; 
}

#bg1{
  background:green;
}
#bg2{
  background:red;
}
#bg3{
  background:blue;
}
#bg4{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="anch0" class="anchor"></a>
<div id="bg1" class="fullpage">

</div>
<a name="anch1" class="anchor"></a>
<div id="bg2" class="fullpage">

</div>
<a name="anch2" class="anchor"></a>
<div id="bg3" class="fullpage">

</div>
<a name="anch3" class="anchor"></a>
<div id="bg4" class="fullpage">

</div>
```

Comment: well. ok ty. I will try and implement your code on my page. TY!!!

Comment: You can try it with the button run code snippet.